# Propagating uncertainties with trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

> I have $$\tan (\frac{2.05 × 10^{-4}± 2.89 × 10^{-6}}{2})=\frac{x}{667.6 × 10^6}$$
>   $$\therefore x = (667.6 × 10^6) \cdot \tan(\frac{2.05 × 10^{-4}± 2.89 × 10^{-6}}{2})$$

As described in the title, I am trying to find the absolute uncertainty. Please include working out.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for values of *x* near zero, like you have here, [$\tan x$ is closely approximated by *x*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation), as can be seen from the Maclaurin series:
$$\tan x=x+\frac{x^3}3+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\cdots$$
Hence to get an approximate uncertainty for *x* the tangent can be ignored:
$$\Delta x\approx667.6\times10^6\cdot\frac{2.89\times10^{-6}}2=965$$
$$x_0=667.6\times10^6\cdot\tan(\frac{2.05\times10^{-4}}2)=68429$$
$$x=68429\pm965$$
If we calculate the actual upper and lower bounds for *x* so as to get an exact absolute uncertainty, we get exactly the same result as with the small-angle approximation, up to working precision:
$$x_+ = 667.6\times10^6\cdot\tan(\frac{2.05\times10^{-4}+2.89\times10^{-6}}2)=69394$$
$$x_- = 667.6\times10^6\cdot\tan(\frac{2.05\times10^{-4}-2.89\times10^{-6}}2)=67464$$
$$x=68429\pm965$$